# Float в input value с помощью jquery mask query

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите как сделать что бы в input можно было вводить дробные (или целые) числа ( пример: 1.1 | 1.234 | 12 ). Тоесть только цифры или точку (не запятая).
Спасибо.

Comment: Можно создать событие keydown и в event перехватывать keyCode
https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="return isNumber(event)">

function isNumber(evt) {
    const charCode = evt.keyCode;
    const hasDot = evt.target.value.indexOf('.') !== -1 && charCode === 190;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode != 190 && charCode > 31 
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) || hasDot) {
        return false;
    }
        return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Для форматов, перечисленных в вопросе, можно использовать такое выражение:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Upd.

Если необходима проверка формата во время ввода, то можно использовать вот такой код:

```js
$("#testField").on("keyup change", function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var validValue = that.data("validValue") || "";
  var newValue = that.val();
  if (newValue.match(/^\d+\.?\d*$/)) {
    that.data("validValue", that.val());
  } else {
    that.val(validValue);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="testField">
```

Тут используется немного другое регулярное выражение `^\d+\.?\d*$`, которое позволяет значения типа `58.`, но такие значения также являются валидными рациональными числами.

Comment: А как мне его дальше использовать? Что бы в инпуте не допускалось ввод символов которых нету в списке

Comment: @G.Denis, обновил ответ.